# Load JSON File into Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to load a JSON file and use the values to perform some actions based on my tests. I tried to load the json value which I think I got right, but when trying to log the output, I got error message:

`Resolving variable '${qa["REQUEST_ID"]}' failed: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Not exactly sure what this means since I am new to Robot Framework. This is what I did to load and log the values:

```
    ${file}     Get File    ${CURDIR}/RequestIDs.json
    ${qa}       Evaluate    json.loads('''${file}''')   json 
    Log To Console          ${qa["REQUEST_ID"]}
```

Json file looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "REQUEST_ID" : 10513
    },
    {
        "REQUEST_ID" : 48156
    },
    {
        "REQUEST_ID" : 455131
    }
]
```

So basically I want to get the `"REQUEST_ID"` value and type that in a text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the structure of your json - it's a list of dictionaries; so you have to first specify which list member you want, and then its REQUEST_ID field:

```
Log To Console          ${qa[0]["REQUEST_ID"]

# print the value from all present dictionaries in the list:
FOR    ${member}    IN    @{qa}
    Log To Console          ${member["REQUEST_ID"]
END
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to Robot Framework as we were using Katalon Recorder previously and exporting the tests to robot now. Didn't know we can use For loop here, so will do more research on the commands used by robot.